# Windows 7 Updates installed in registry

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

Does any one know where the information about Windows 7 Updates is stored in the Registry because its no longer in:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for a list of installed updates, you can use the "systeminfo" command at the command line, the list is contained within the "Hotfixe(s)" section.

Comment: Actually no. Im trying to write a software. That works for previous version of windows just not 7 (Havent Tried Vista)

Comment: I would +1 but req 15 rep. Cause i didnt know about the systeminfo command :D

Answer (score 0):

Check `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages`.

To list them in a `cmd` window, open an elevated command prompt and paste in:

`REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages" /s /v InstallClient /t REG_SZ /f WindowsUpdateAgent | grep -oPh "KB[0-9]{4,8}" | sort | uniq`

This isn't an ideal way of retrieving the installed updates, since it relies on UNIX tools being installed to filter in the `KBs`, and sort & dedupe the list. But if you have `Github Desktop` or `Git SCM` installed you probably have those tools in your `PATH` already.